# data streams using queries vs synchronised data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have set up several SQL queries in multiple business units and these run in automation studio. The issue now is that this is slowing the environment and some queries do not run and therefore populate the DE.

I would like to explore using synchronized data extensions but I need to be able to filter the data synced across by a business unit and then by a specified audience - Is this possible with synchronized data extensions?

Comment: You should be able to create a filter on the top level sync'd DE and then share the filtered DE with only the corresponding BU below it.  You would need to put the filters into AS, but they take much less processing and run much quicker than Queries

Comment: Okay, so I can create filters in AS using source from the sync DE to then populate the DE as and when I need them to?